# Hitting an OutOfMemory Exception in my Android App at Activity launch

Tags: java, android

Before anything I'd like to point out that I am new to android and this is a college assignment and it required me to store all my images in the application itself. So I cannot use CDN's or DB's or whatever else.

So my issue is an OOM Error thats being caused from my FlipperView, I have 10 JPEG images that need to be processed as a slideshow and I can't seem to prevent this from happening. I don't know if its the images that are causing the error or whether its the way I'm filling in the View.

#### The Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app.doggyroulette, PID: 9533
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 8523350032 byte allocation with 1720176 free bytes and 382MB until OOM, max allowed footprint 3440352, growth limit 402653184
        at com.app.doggyroulette.Search.onCreate(Search.java:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

#### The Code

This is the activity dedicated to making it right now.

Just to clarify some stuff so its easier to understand. The breedMap is a hashmap that contains a Dog breed (such as "Golden Retriever") as a key and its file code ("gr") as a value. The get resourceID method is a method i made to get the resourceID of an image file.

```
public class Search extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String[] breedList;
    TextView searchTxt;
    ViewFlipper imageFlipper;
    Map<String, String> breedMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        breedList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.breeds);
        searchTxt = findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
        imageFlipper = findViewById(R.id.imageFlipper);
        breedMap = AppUtility.createMap(new String[R.array.breeds], new String[R.array.breedsId]);

        setup();
    }

    public void setup(){
        String imageBreedClass = "";

        for(Map.Entry<String, String> mapEntries : breedMap.entrySet()){
            String key = mapEntries.getKey();
            String val = mapEntries.getValue();

            if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(searchTxt.getText().toString())){
                imageBreedClass = val;
            }
        }

        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
            int resID = AppUtility.getResourceID(imageBreedClass+i, this.getApplicationContext());
            setBreedImage(resID);
        }
    }

    public void setBreedImage(int imageID){
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

        imageView.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(imageID));

        imageFlipper.addView(imageView);
        imageFlipper.setFlipInterval(1000);
        imageFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
        imageFlipper.setInAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        imageFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }
}
```

Is there anything that I can do to avoid this be it programatically or even something like compressing my images (Although considering my images themselves are already about 2.5 to 5kb per photo I dont know how much more smaller they can get)

Comment: Use `ViewPager` instead of `ViewFlipper`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler is there a way to automate the switching though?

Answer (score 1):

According to log, you app tries to allocate something like 8 gb of ram, which is quite a lot. So, i advice you to look at resolution of jpegs you are trying to load (100_000*100_000 jpeg, despite of it's small size will crash app) or simply use image loading library, lika [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/), which would handle this hassle for you.

Comment: I already considered it, but according to my coursework spec. Im only allowed to used native android libraries and not 3rd party ones. Is there any other solution?

Comment: If this is coursework, i strongly advice you to read docs - https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap about handling bitmap, to get the idea of what you are doing and why it is happening.